# Object has no attribute but attribute is defined

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have defined an attribute in a custom class, but I keep receiving an AttributeError when I try to access it.

```
class SMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Constructor
        super(SMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.myapp = PyQtApp()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label_text = ''
        self.settings = scrudb.retrieve_settings('current')
        self.competition = self.retrieve_competition()
        self.set_competition(self.competition.id)
        self.label = QLabel(self.label_text)
        self.button_scrutineer = QPushButton('Scrutineer Competition')
        self.button_comps = QPushButton('Change Competition')
        self.button_comp = QPushButton('Edit Competition Details')
        self.button_dancers = QPushButton('Add/Edit Competitors')
        self.button_judges = QPushButton('Add/Edit Judges')
        self.button_dancerGroups = QPushButton(
            'Define Competitor Groups & Dances')
        self.button_import = QPushButton('Import CSV')
        self.button_delete = QPushButton('Delete Competition')
        self.button_exit = QPushButton('Exit')
        self.button_comps.clicked.connect(self.select_competition)
        self.button_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_competition)
        self.button_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit_app)
        if (self.competition == None):
            self.disable_buttons()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_scrutineer)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_comps)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_comp)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_dancers)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_judges)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_dancerGroups)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_import)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_delete)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_exit)
        self.myapp.setLayout(self.layout)

    def set_competition(self, comp_id):
        self.competition = scrudb.retrieve_competition(comp_id)
        if (self.competition != None):
            self.label_text = ('<center>Competition:<br><strong>%s</strong><br>%8s<br>%s</center>' % (self.competition.name, self.get_formatted_date(self.competition.eventDate), self.competition.location))
            self.label.setText(self.label_text)
            self.settings.lastComp = self.competition.id
            scrudb.set_settings(self.settings)
            return self.competition
        else:
            self.label_text = ('<center>No Competition Selected</center>')
            return None
```

File "/Users/majikpig/mu_code/src/main/python/scruinterface1.py", line 182, in set_competition

self.label.setText(self.label_text)

AttributeError: 'SMainWindow' object has no attribute 'label'

Comment: You're calling `set_competition` before `self.label` has been created.

Comment: Hi Matt! In order to get quality answers please make sure to post quality questions. Try to be more precise with the topic and remove all of the noise from the description. Perhaps you may want to limit the code to the lines which are important.

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change order of fields ... in `set competition` function you try to access field, which you haven't defined yet.

```
self.set_competition(self.competition.id)
self.label = QLabel(self.label_text)
```